# How do I change a node ID?

Tags: nodes, database

I have a node whose ID is 548754. I need it to be 301.

Is there a safe way to do this? There are a lot of tables related to 548754.
What if I export the database, open the SQL file, replace the number, and then import the database. Will this work?

Comment: Why do you need to change the nid? It's better don't do that imho, if you explain the problem because you want to change maybe we can find a workaround.
Read [this](http://www.drupal.org/node/256676)

Comment: it should work if you change `nid` and `entity_id` in all tables, but you can not know if some modules didn't named it just `id`. There yould be a problem if you replace it in editor like a string.

Comment: I understand...

Comment: Not possible, unless want to re-import/re-write your whole database. If you consider that, I could answer how potentially this can be done in few commands.

Comment: @kenorb Not really true, all you actually need is a list of the table and field names that make reference to the node ID. Don't need to re-import or rewrite for that, just needs some domain knowledge and perserverence

Comment: It all depends on the complexity. So it could, but on clean-like Drupal installation, on matured project with hundred of modules, extra links in the content, the nids are spread everywhere - it's few hour work (very specific work depending which modules are used). Not to mention some content links, serialized data (in case some components stores it in this way) which could have some references to it.

Comment: The easiest would be something like: `drush sql-dump --ordered-dump | sed s/548754/301/g > new.sql; cat new.sql | drush sqlc` (assuming 301 doesn't exist and nothing else conflicts with 548754). This won't be bullet-proof for serialized data which would break in that case (if serialized data is cache, can be removed).

Comment: @chefnelone Run: `drush sql-dump --ordered-dump | grep -w 548754 | grep -o '\`.*\`' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` and paste the results please (which should list all the tables which references to `548754`.

Comment: @chefnelone Btw. Are you really have over 0.5mln nodes in the database, or it's just an example? Are you asking for the production or some testing db which you assume it won't work for the first time and you've the proper CI/tests in place?

Comment: @kenorb it is a production site. It doesn't have that amount of nodes, but I got huge nid values because I'm using feeds to import external content. I will try your method, I need some time...

Comment: @chefnelone Test it on local of course and check which tables are affected (by above cmd) and if matches any serialized data, then you've to exclude that + ignore [some common tables](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/176926/1908). Once you know the list of tables which have this nid, then you could also consider to write some SQL queries to ALTER these values manually.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is using these two contrib modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_nid
- https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_clone

They turn out to work together nicely. "Custom nid" only works for new nodes.. however "Quick node clone" takes you to an unsubmitted "new node" form... as such you can change the nid of the clone before saving it.
After cloning you can throw away the original.