# How do I backup a site when it weights is more than 200MB and host can't do it?

Tags: backups

How do I backup a site when it weights is more than 200MB and host can't do it? I have it on hostinger.ru and can't backup with Internet server error 500. I cleared cache and deleted some modules.

Comment: Can you backup to your server and then download it through FTP? Is it just timing out when you try and download? I use FTP to download the site files and only use Backup and Migrate to download the database file. BUT, I have Backup and Migrate set up to backup to my server every night, then I download the backup's via FTP.

Comment: backup and migrate module is installed and it does the job after the removal of some modules and cache clearing, ftp can`t cope with size more than 200 MB, thx, should I increase execution time or do some other settings?

Comment: do you want backup the site or the database?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to my answer to "[Which tables are safe to clear?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22041/which-drupal-tables-are-safe-to-clear/171884#171884)", which should help to get the size of your database reduced.

And/or use the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module, which also support exclusion of selected tables (typically the ones that are safe to clear also). Here is a quote from its project page (bold markup added here):

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. **You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default**.